# Handle POST request from XML HTTP in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

Hi and good day everyone,

as per above title, I was trying to handle POST request from XML HTTP in WCF. Actually, I can already handle the request by using HTTP Web Request, but since old library sends the request in this form (as in the code, we are using MSXML2 namespace), we will have to maintain the requirement here.

Here are the codes for the front-end (the old library that will send the request)

```
MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP xmlhttp = new MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP();                 
xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost/RestService/RestServiceImpl.svc/auth", false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/2.0.2");
String ClientRequest = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone= ""yes""?>   <RequestData xmlns=""http://www.eysnap.com/mPlayer""> <details>Ashu|29|7 Years|.NET</details></RequestData>";

xmlhttp.send(ClientRequest);
int readyState = xmlhttp.readyState;
int status = xmlhttp.status;
```

While here are the codes for the WCF, which I failed to handle it:

```
public ResponseData Auth(RequestData rData)        
    {
        try
        {
            Logger.log.Info("attempting to send request");
            // Call BLL here
            var data = rData.details.Split('|');

            var response = new ResponseData                
            {
                Name = data[0],
                Age = data[1],
                Exp = data[2],
                Technology = data[3]
            };

            Logger.log.Info("Sending request...");
            return response;
        }

        catch(System.Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.log.Fatal(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

In the web.config, I already change the binding to "customBinding" instead of "webHttpBinding" because I was getting error on RAW format instead of JSON format for the request.

After searching through the forum and other sites, I tried on changing the web.config accordingly but got xmlhttp status 400 (Bad Request) instead.

Thanks in advance for the advices.

Comment: Have you tried to monitor your request using Fiddler? Also the RAW message was due to your request not setting the Content-Type header property. Just set it to either application/xml or application/json and that should get resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to monitor your request using Fiddler and see how the RAW request looks like. It should be something like below:

```
POST http://localhost/RestService/RestServiceImpl.svc/auth HTTP/2.0
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: 47

<RequestData xmlns="http://www.eysnap.com/mPlayer"xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><details>Ashu|29|7 Years|.NET</details></RequestData>
```

Comment: Hi Rajesh, thanks for the reply. I changed Content-Type header:     xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");

It works! I now can change the xml input to the WCF and get the status 200. 

However, for the monitoring using Fiddler, I did open up Fiddler, but I am not sure if I got this right:

Comment: How I post json this xml with property xmlns? I using by node.js request.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply. I changed Content-Type header:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
```

It works! I now can change the xml input to the WCF and get the status 200.

However, for the monitoring using Fiddler, I did open up Fiddler, but I am not sure if I got this right:

```
POST http://localhost:3015/default.aspx HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Referer: http://localhost:3015/default.aspx
Accept-Language: en-MY
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: localhost:3015
Content-Length: 220
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=qdzso1frp32nzw1yyca0xkev

    __VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUKLTUwNDQwMTA1MGRk2SgUm9rav%2BZYiqZHo5PtLZx1Eh67%2BxU309q4TRd3NLU%3D&    __EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWBAKr8%2BqJAQLj5PzKCwKM54rGBgLs0bLrBr7W%2BQ74Ywyf9FnYR2DQIpRMPmXllwC5V5bOZfXnofpY&Button1=XML+HTTP&TextBox1=
```

Thus, I did not get the expected result like in your last post. Is there any additional setting that I should do first before opening up my sample web application?

By the way, how can I remove namespace from Data Contract?

```
<RequestData xmlns=""http://www.eysnap.com/mPlayer""><details>Ashu|29|7 Years|.NET</details></RequestData>
```

is the old request, I tried to change to:

```
<RequestData><details>Ashu|29|7 Years|.NET</details></RequestData>
```

and in RequestData class as well:

```
[DataContract()]    
public class RequestData
{
    [DataMember]        
    public string details { get; set; }
}
```

this is because actually existing request does not have namespace. Now I am getting error 400 for removing the namespace. Would it be possible to remove namespace in first place?

Thanks

Edited: I change DataContract to:

```
[DataContract(Namespace="")]    
public class RequestData
{
    [DataMember]        
    public string details { get; set; }
}
```

and managed to get HTTP status to 200! Now I am trying to change the request xml to the one that our existing application use.

Comment: The above request is when you perform a button click on a web page its posting the data to the server that is being captured in fiddler. In a similar way when you make a call to the web service it would be captured.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not sure how to get the result captured in fiddler, yet. But I guess I will be making some sample application first for that :)

Comment: Just install Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and then before you perform the call to your service just open Fiddler. It would capture any traffic on port 80.

Comment: I did that just now, but is the result in Inspectors -> RAW ? 

Because I am getting the same one as in my previous post in Fiddler2

The host is localhost:3015

Comment: I think fiddler cannot intercept traffic on other ports. Try to put your project on IIS and then give it a try

Comment: Thanks, will do. :)

By the way, as for the application header, is there any way that I can handle the RAW XML request from the server side instead of client side? 

This is because I forgot that client side need to stick with old parameters (without the new application header that I added in previous post)..