# Retrieve Inner XML in WCF from XMLHTTP POST Request

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

Hi and good day everyone,

I am able to send XML HTTP POST Request to WCF after solving it through this topic: [Handle POST request from XML HTTP in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887002/handle-post-request-from-xml-http-in-wcf)

But right now, I am still trying to find right way to retrieve inner XML from the request. I send the request in XML form :

```
 <?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone= ""yes""?><AFISQuery transid=""3356434""><Request CIFNO =""1234567890123456789"" IC= ""770707-07-7777"">TEST</Request></AFISQuery>
```

In the AFISQuery class, I set it as:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class AFISQuery
{
    public AFISQuery(string transid)
    {
        this.transid = transid;
    }

    [DataMember]        
    public string Request { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string transid { get; set; }
}
```

As the result, I am able to get Request information ("TEST"), but could not get transid information. I tried to look around the forums but failed to find similar problems.

My question is, would it be possible to retrieve the information from the inner XML of the request? For this instance, they are CIFNo, transid and ICNo.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're able to retrieve Request is that Request is an XML element. XML elements map directly to DataMembers, and as a result, Request is deserialized properly to the Request DataMember on the AFISQuery data contract type.

The problem with 'transid' is that it's an attribute. Attributes are not supported with DataContractSerializer, and they cannot in any way be supported. You need to change your request XML so that it has transid as an element, just like Request is an element.

Note also that even though Request is set to a value for you right now, the attributes on the "Request" element in the XML you have are totally ignored. You may or may not be OK with this.

If you care about attributes, or if you do want to support serializable members as attributes, you may need to switch to XmlSerializer from DataContractSerializer. It's easy to do this, just decorate the services or operations you care about -- that you want to switch over to XmlSerializer -- with [XmlSerializerFormat.]